# В чем разница между Int32 и UInt32?

Tags: .net

В чем разница между Int32 и UInt32?

Вопрос о том, для чего был создан UInt32?

Когда я должен использовать UInt32 вместо Int32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UInt32 не допускает отрицательных чисел. Вот пояснения [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):

Этот тип значений UInt32 представляет из себя целое 32-разрядное число без знака со значениями от 0 до 4 294 967 295 (2^32).

Integer 32 представляет из себя число в диапазоне -2 147 483 648 to 2 147 483 647, а  Unsigned Integer 32  от 0 до 4 294 967 295.

Для большего понимания надо понимать что  UInt32  это  32-разрядное целое число без знака, которое можно представить 2 ^ 32 числа (0-4 294 967 295). Однако для предоставления отрицательных чисел требуется "изъять" один бит из 32-х битов, для указания либо положительного либо отрицательного числа. Это оставляет вам 2 ^ 31 возможных чисел как в положительном диапазоне так и в отрицательном диапазоне. Диапазон 2 ^ 31 составляет от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 *(положительный диапазон также включает число 0, следовательно только 2 147 483 647 )* такой тип значений называется Int32.

На практике UInt32 число используется, там где значения не могут быть отрицательными, поскольку он предполагает больший диапазон. Также стит не забывать что преобразование (прямое) из UInt32 в Int32 невозможно, так как Int32 не может содержать диапазон UInt32, и на оборот.

Comment: Эээ. Зачем вы задаёте вопрос и сами же на него отвечаете? Причём вопрос гуглится без проблем

Comment: @ArchDemon потому что могу